# "INVALID_PARAMETERS" error response when sending a PUT request to Email Octopus

Tags: php, json, http, post

When a user signs up, 
we send an HTTPS PUT request to Email Octopus 
in order to add that user to an email marketing list.

This PUT request includes the following user`s data:

- email
- first name
- last name
- country

We followed the guidelines here: 
https://emailoctopus.com/api-documentation

We also followed the same syntax as mentioned here: 
https://emailoctopus.com/api-documentation/lists/create-contact

However, we get an "Invalid Parameters" response.

**Any idea what are we doing wrong?**

We send the following request:

```
https://emailoctopus.com/api/1.5/lists/<list-id>/contacts array(4) 
{
  ["email_address"]=> string(23) "test_email@yopmail.com"
  ["fields"]=> array(3) 
  {
    ["FirstName"] => string(4) "test_firstname"
    ["LastName"]  => string(4) "test_lastname"
    ["Country"]   => string(5) "India"
  }
  ["status"]   => string(10) "SUBSCRIBED"
  ["api_key"]  => string(36) "<api-key>"
}
```

We get the following response:

```
string(86) "{"error":{"code":"INVALID_PARAMETERS","message":"Parameters are missing or invalid."}}"
```

We send the request using PHP CURL function.

```
function create_emailoctopus_contact($args) 
{
    $api_key = get_field('emailoctopus_api_key', 'option');
    $list_id = get_field('emailoctopus_list_id', 'option');

    if ($api_key && $list_id && count($args)):
       $args['api_key'] = $api_key;
    
       $data = json_encode($args);
       $url = 'https://emailoctopus.com/api/1.5/lists/<list-id>/contacts';
       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt_array($curl, array (
              CURLOPT_URL => $url,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        endif;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with EmailOctopus support, 
we **fixed** the issue by doing the following: 
We added the following header to our HTTPS request:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type:application/json']
```